# Software to retroactively outline and collapse (legal) documents

Tags: reading, legal

My job requires to work a lot with complicated legal documents that are unstructured and complex. I would like to import a document and define regions where I could collapse whole sections. This would make reading and working with a document way easier.

Look for example at [this PDF](https://www.pwc.com/us/en/financial-services/publications/fatca-publications/assets/pwc_formatted_regulations_fatca.pdf?source=publications) (start at around pg. 40). If there was a software to (if needed manually) define the different sections and make them collapsible the document would be way easier to read and work with.

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: Windows if possible. I have a (private) Mac which I could use but I would prefer to use work equipment, which is on Windows obviously.